# Как запретить переход ссылки по клику, но выполнить функцию

Tags: javascript

как можно реализовать запрет перехода по ссылки, но при этом выполнить функцию замены href

```
function l_image4 (a) {
  document.example_img13.src = a + '.png';
    
}

<a  href="javascript:l_image4('images/etika/672501')"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="images/etika/672501.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Белый</div></div></a>
```

Пробовал так:

```
     function l_image4 (a) {
       e.PreventDefault;   
document.example_img13.src = a + '.png';
             
        }
```

и так :

```
function l_image4 (a) {
    document.example_img13.src = a + '.png';
          return false;      
            }
```

и +так

```
<a href="javascript:l_image4('images/etika/672501')" onclick="return l_image4();">
```

Либо не работает и ссылка и функция, либо функция ломается.

Без всех этих действий, работает только один раз после загрузки страницы, но как только нажать на какую либо кнопку (той же функции или другой) ссылка начинает переходить. На локалке все работает как надо без переходов

```
Код на сайте https://euroelectric.kz/konfigurator2

Код без картинок https://codepen.io/Axel0303/pen/gOmEmvz
```

Причем аналогичная функция но в другом месте кода (там где выбирать текстуру) работает без перехода. Поэтому думаю дело в общей структуре всего кода, а не только в этом кусочке.

П\С: Надеюсь теперь я правильно сформулировал вопрос, товарищ модератор

Comment: Если вам не нужен переход по ссылке, уберите `href` или сделайте `href="javascript:void"`.

Comment: для того чтобы использовать `e.PreventDefault` Вам нужно две вещи: чтобы у функции был аргумент `e`, и в её вызов передавать собсно объект события (не помню какой у него тип).

Comment: Если вам не нужен переход по ссылке, уберите href или сделайте href="javascript:void".

Можно поподробней про href="javascript:void" . Откуда будет тогда браться адрес картинки?? 

Я не против если убрать href, но как это сделать более оптимально. От примера бы не отказался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы отловил клик каждого элемента "a" в нужном блоке и получал из атрибута "data" данные для подмены

И мне не понятно почему у вас JS код половина на чистом js, а половина на JQuery. Вы либо пишите полностью на JS, либо полностью на JQuery. Глаза начинают разбегаться.

```js
$('.container a').on('click', function()
{
  alert($(this).data('img'))
})
```

```css
.container a
{
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgrey;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a data-img="1-img.png">1</a>
  <a data-img="2-img.png">2</a>
  <a data-img="3-img.png">3</a>
  <a data-img="4-img.png">4</a>
  <a data-img="5-img.png">5</a>
  <a data-img="6-img.png">6</a>
</div>
```

Дополню в связи с последним комментарием под моим ответом!

```js
$('.container a').on('click', function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 alert(`Старое значение атрибута href: ${$(this).attr('href')}`);
 $(this).attr({"href": "new-img.png"});
 alert(`Новое значение атрибута href: ${$(this).attr('href')}`);
})
```

```css
.container a
{
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <a href="1-img.png">1</a>
 <a href="2-img.png">2</a>
 <a href="3-img.png">3</a>
 <a href="4-img.png">4</a>
 <a href="5-img.png">5</a>
 <a href="6-img.png">6</a>
</div>
```

Думаю все проверки сделаете аналогичным образом, я уже не стал вникать в них исходя из вашего кода, но думаю вам будет понятно.

```js
$('#mCSB_2_container a').on('click', l_image2);

     function l_image2 (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#example_img2').attr({src: $(this).attr('href')});
    }

    $('#mCSB_4_container a').on('click', l_image3);

     function l_image3 (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href')});
    }
```

```css
.container a
        {
          display: block;
          width: 30px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          background: lightgrey;
         }

         #example_img2
         {
            position: relative;
            left: 29px;
         }

         #example_img
         {
            position: relative;
            left: -170px;
            top: -21px;
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<img id="example_img2" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/vikl/legrand_etika_672601.png">
<img src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/neo.png" class="ramka1img" name="example_img" id="example_img" alt="">
    
    <div class="container" id="mCSB_4_container">
        <h3>Выберите рамку</h3>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501.png">1</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672511.png">2</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672521.png">3</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672531.png">4</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="mCSB_2_container">
        <h3>Выберите механизм</h3>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/vikl/legrand_etika_672601.png">1</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/vikl/legrand_etika_672401.png">2</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/vikl/legrand_etika_672301.png">3</a>
      <a href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/vikl/legrand_etika_672201.png">4</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: И как ваш код предотвращает переход? Только благодаря тому, что `href` исчез? Автор хочет заменить атрибут href при клике, а его и вовсе нет. У автора вопроса нет ни строчки jQuery.

Comment: Перейдите по добавленной ссылке к исходному коду и все увидите. К дополнению можно же добавить PreventDefault и заблокировать ему дальнейшие действия если так сильно нужен атрибут `href`!

Comment: Код собрать из разных примеров и то что jq это как раз логика из примеров, так как я его не знаю, а на js это больше кода как правило. 

И данный способ с а href был взят потому что он меленький и легко засунуть например сюда

 else if (document.getElementById('radio-4').checked) {     
  document.example_img.src = a + 'post2' +'.png';
    }

Можете дать пример с моими переменными, а то что то $('.container a').on('click', function(e) путает. Обязательно ли делать через "e" или можно сделать через другую букву. И как их тогда называть эти фикции чтоб они при клике отрабатывали

Comment: Все таки там в основной функции не только есть href , но и другие действия

Comment: А как тогда добавить туда переменные, ну попробовал типо
  $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href')} + 'post2' + '.png'); чет не пашет, как это правильнее сделать?

Comment: Можете так $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + post2 + '.png'});

Comment: Чета пока не получается, давайте на этом примере, напишу в новом комменте

Comment: А когда у вас js с функциями вашими подгружается? В начале страницы?

Comment: Нет конечно, стили - боди - сткрипты

Answer (score 0):

@隼SAPSAN Вот пример кода, куда хочу интегрировать, тоесть это все должно работать в этой связке. Но этот вариант почему то не работает. Точнее и переход происходит и переменные не добавляются в ссылке

```js
    $('#mCSB_4_container a').on('click', l_image3);

function l_image3 (event) {
event.preventDefault();




 if (document.getElementById('radio-1').checked) { 
 if (document.getElementById('radio-3').checked) {
      
        $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + '.png'});
    }
   else if (document.getElementById('radio-4').checked) {     
  $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + 'post2' + '.png'});
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-5').checked) {

 $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href' )+ 'post3' + '.png'} );
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-6').checked) { 
 $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href' )+ 'post4' + '.png'} );
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-7').checked) { 
 $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href' )+ 'post5' + '.png'} );
    }
    } 
 else if (document.getElementById('radio-2').checked) {
     if (document.getElementById('radio-3').checked) {
      $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + '.png'});
    }   
     else if (document.getElementById('radio-4').checked) { 
  $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + 'post22' + '.png'});
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-5').checked) {    
 $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + 'post33' + '.png'});
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-6').checked) {
      $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + 'post44' + '.png'});
   
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-7').checked) {
    
  $('#example_img').attr({src: $(this).attr('href') + 'post55' + '.png'});
 
    }

    }
    



}
  //массив данных
  
  const arr22 = [
      // Категория 1, категория 2, href, src, text
      ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Белый"],
      ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672511", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672511.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Слоновая кость"],
       ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672521", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672521.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Светлая галька"],
        ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672531", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672531.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Красный"],
         ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672541", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672541.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Зеленый папоротник"],
              ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Алюминий"],
           ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Сливовый"],
              ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672571", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672571.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Какао"],
               ["etika", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672581", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672581.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Антрацит"],
          ["valenaclass", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Белый"],
           ["valenalife", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Белый"],
            ["valenaallure", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Белый"],
             ["celiane", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501", "https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501.png", "<b>Etika</b><br>Белый"],
             
    ];

    const collectValue22 = document.getElementById("display_avatar2").value;
    const content_el12 = document.querySelector(".ere6");
    content_el12.innerHTML = arr22
      .filter(([collect]) => {
        return (collectValue22 == "allleg" || collectValue22 == collect)  
      })
      .map(([collect, href, src, text]) => `
        <a   href="${href}" > <div class="varic1">
            <img class="notact2" src="${src}" />
          <div>${text}</div>
        </div></a>
      `).join("");
```

```html
 <img src="images/etika/672501.png" class="ramka1img" name="example_img" id="example_img" alt="">
 
 
   <div class="config-settings__block config-settings__block_posts2"><div class="config-settings__title">
                                    Ориентация рамки
                                </div>
        <div class="form_radiosa">                      
<div class="form_radio">
    <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-1"></label>
</div>
 
<div class="form_radio2">
    <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2" onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-2"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="config-settings__block config-settings__block_posts">
                                <div class="config-settings__title">
                                    Количество постов
                                </div>
            <div class="form_radio4">                     
                                       <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3" type="radio" name="radio22" value="3" checked  onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-3" >1</label>
</div>
 
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-4" type="radio" name="radio22" value="4" onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-4" >2</label>
</div>
 
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-5" type="radio" name="radio22" value="5" onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-5" >3</label>
</div>
 
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-6" type="radio" name="radio22" value="6" onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-6" >4</label>
</div>
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-7" type="radio" name="radio22" value="7" onclick="return someFunc();">
    <label for="radio-7" >5</label>
</div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="ere6" id="mCSB_4_container"> <div class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark" >
<a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672501.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Белый</div></div></a>
<a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672511"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672511.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Слоновая кость</div></div></a>
<a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672521"  >  <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672521.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Светлая галька</div></div></a>
<a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672531"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672531.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Красный</div></div></a>
 <a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672541"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672541.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Зеленый папоротник</div></div></a>
 <a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551"  >  <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672551.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Алюминий</div></div></a>
  <a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561"  >  <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672561.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Сливовый</div></div></a>
    <a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672571"  > <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672571.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Какао</div></div></a>
    <a  href="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672581"  >  <div class="varic1"> <img class="notact" src="https://euroelectric.kz/images/etika/672581.png"><div><b>Etika</b><br>Антрацит</div></div></a>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

onclick="l_image4();"

UPD.

Вот что я имел ввиду. В событие onclick пихаем функцию, а в href решетку. функция должна возвращать false.

Все работает, я проверил.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function l_image4 (a) {
            document.getElementById("example_img13").setAttribute("src", a + '.png');
            return false;
        }
    </script>

    <a  href="#" onclick="l_image4('images/etika/672502')">
        <div class="varic1">
            <img class="notact" id="example_img13" src="images/etika/672501.png">
            <div>
                <b>Etika</b>
                <br>Белый
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: не работает, так же перекидывает

Comment: @УолиКлуд `onclick="l_image4();return false;"`, тогда будет блок на переход из-за этого `return`

Comment: @alex Старайся писать более развернутые ответы

Comment: onclick="l_image4();return false;", тогда будет блок на переход из-за этого return – Vladimir Gonchar 
Этот вариант тоже не работает, точнее функция работает, но теряется картинка

Comment: картинка теряется потому что надо учить мат часть. ничего что ваш метод l_image() ждет аргумент, который вы не хотите передать? все надо за вас делать. думалкой работать надо. хотя бы немного... пожалуйста...